# Delay in undoing downvote?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, down-votes

Simple enough : I answered this question

https://superuser.com/questions/45336/locked-my-alias-how-do-i-unlock-it/45353#45353

And thought nothing more of it. Then i check my 'latest' button, and it shows that someone marked my answer down about 20 minutes ago losing me two rep. I visit the post...and there's no downvote there. Does this mean someone marked me down, then removed it, and there's a delay in the update? Or some weird bug?

Comment: You told them to Google it? Really surprised you didn't get more downvotes.

Comment: Don't worry, I downvoted it but this time it's easier to understand ;)

Comment: I said they SHOULD have Googled it - it was the first result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer was basically: Google it.

Someone justifiably downvoted you. You lost two rep. The answer was marked with **-1**

Then someone for some reason upvoted you. You got 10 rep. The answer is now marked **0**.

Take a look at the reputation chart at the time, and you'll note the points swing with the votes.

> [image: always sunny in vote-adelphia]

Comment: FWIW, this answer is provably correct - CodeByMoonlight's Reputation page indicates both votes.

Comment: Of course, that means it's business time.

Comment: I think i'll chalk this up to clearly not being alert today...

Comment: However, I see answers much less kind than mine was fairly regularly, without the downvotes I have now acquired which usually accrue to the question, not an answer.

Comment: Depends on who's passing through and voting as to if/when you'll see the unfriendly and hostile type of answers dealt with.